# I'm not able to link html file in html

Tags: html, hyperlink

```html
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        learning web dev 
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" target=blank > Google </a>
    <a herf="index2.html">next page</a>
</body>
</html>
the google link works but next page link just showing text
```

Comment: "href", not "herf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your markup (herf instead of href)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a typo in your code, it should be `href`, also please check if you have the `index2.html` file in same folder as your existing html, if not then please provide a path for it in `href` attribute.

```html
<html>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        learning web dev 
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" target=blank > Google </a>
    <a href="index2.html">next page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

herf should be href
here is working code

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target=blank > Google </a>
   <a href="index2.html">next page</a>
```